# How to write multiple parquet files in parallel in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, parquet

I want to split the dataframe into two dataframes and write them into two separate parquet files like this

```
df = attachment_df.flatMap(process_attachment).toDF()

large_df = df.filter(df.is_large_file == True)
small_df = df.filter(df.is_large_file == False)

(large_df.write
    .mode("overwrite")
    .parquet('large_dummy'))

(small_df.write
    .mode("overwrite")
    .parquet('small_dummy'))
```

However, the above code will write in sequential and it looks like the process_attachment function is called twice for each attachment. I really want to avoid duplicate computation because it is very expensive to process an attachment.

Is there a way to avoid duplicate processing of attachment and write in parallel? I don't want to write to a single parquet file using partition by is_large_file column.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you get the solution? Can you please update?

Answer (score 4):

When spark writes, it writes in parallel for each dataframe (based on the number of partitions). So you are basically doing serially two parallel tasks (i.e. that shouldn't have much effect).
The main problem is that currently you are recalculating df twice.

The reason for that is that the DAG is calculated separately for each action (writing is an action).

If you have enough memory you can improve this simply by doing df.cache() before the first write and df.unpersist after the second write. This will keep in memory the calculation of df when it can (i.e. there is enough memory).

If you do not have enough memory and process_attachment is really long you can try to use persist with MEMORY_AND_DISK option which would spill the calculation to disk if it is too large (i.e. you will reload from disk instead of recalculating).